# A Group Isomorphic to $D_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism, dihedral-groups

How to find a group isomorphic to $D_8$ consisting of elements of $GL(2,\Bbb C)$?

How about $GL(2,\Bbb R)$?

---

Answer:
As we know $D_8=\{e, a, a^2, a^3, b, ab, a^2b, a^3b\}$ and $a^4=b^2=e, ba= a^3b$.

Obviously:
$$e=\left[\begin{matrix}
1&0\\
0&1\\
\end{matrix}\right]$$

If $$a=\left[\begin{matrix}
0&1\\
-1&0\\
\end{matrix}\right]$$ and $$b=\left[\begin{matrix}
0&1\\
1&0\\
\end{matrix}\right]$$
Is it true?

We should prove $\phi: D_8 \rightarrow G$ is $1-1$ and onto and $$\phi(a*b)=\phi(a)\cdot\phi(b)$$

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The isometries of a square in $\mathbb{R}^2$ form a group isomorphic to $D_8$. If you center the square at the origin, each isometry can be represented by a linear transformation (like a rotation or a reflection), which can be written as a $2 \times 2$ real matrix.